# How can I convert the following docker command to docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to mount the data of the remote directory locally

```
docker run -d -it  --name redis \
 --mount src=airflow-dags,target=/app/dags,type=volume,volume-driver=vieux/sshfs \
 -p 6379:6379 \
 redis
```

this is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.3}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql+mysqldb://root:xxxx@xxxxxx:3306/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql+mysqldb://root:xxxxx@xxxxx:3306/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+mysql://root:xxxxx@xxxx:3306/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@xxxxx:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - airflow:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"

services:
  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  airflow:
    name: airflow-dags
    external: true
```

I have built a data volume externally

```
docker volume create --driver vieux/sshfs \
    -o sshcmd=xxxx@xxxxx:xxxxx \
    -o password=xxxxxxxxxx \
    airflow-dags
```

If I can mount successfully using the docker command, I will fail using docker compose

If docker compose is used, the file permission will be abnormal.

I can not access this file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r07U0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Because my container permissions are not set properly, the folder cannot be accessed

```
volumes:
  airflow:
    name: airflow_airflow
    driver: vieux/sshfs
    driver_opts:
      sshcmd: yourusername@yourhost:/dir/XXX/XXX
      password: xxxxxx
```

You need to set the user field in your docker compose to 0 so that your files can be accessed

```
  user: "0"
```

you also can add field `allow_other: ""`

```
volumes:
  airflow:
    name: airflow_airflow
    driver: vieux/sshfs
    driver_opts:
      allow_other: ""
      sshcmd: xxxx@xxxxxxx:/root/airflow/dags
      password: xxxx
```